# Populate grouped tables from php and filtered by jquery using ajax json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, pdo

I have two php files. fetch.php creates the filtered array (filter from leagueboxes.php) and passes it back to the leagueboxes.php through ajax json.

fetch.php

```
<?php 

include_once 'dbconfig.php';

if(isset($_GET['filter'])){

    $filter = $_GET['filter'];

    $query ="SELECT box_id, league_id, position, ";
    $query .="(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(U.first_name, ' 
',U.last_name) SEPARATOR ' & ')FROM reg_players RP,users U ";
    $query .="WHERE RP.id = LE.reg_num AND U.id = RP.user)AS player, ";
    $query .="points, place ";  
    $query .="FROM league_entries LE ";
    $query .="JOIN round_league_boxes2 RLB ON RLB.id = 
LE.round_league_box_id ";
    $query .="JOIN leagues L ON L.id = RLB.league_id ";
    $query .="JOIN boxes B ON B.id = RLB.box_id ";
    $query .="WHERE league_id =:league ";
    $query .="ORDER BY round_league_box_id, position";

    $stmnt = $DB_con->prepare($query);
    $stmnt->bindParam(":league",$filter);
    $stmnt->execute();

    $final=$stmnt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($final);
}
?>
```

leagueboxes.php

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
include_once 'header.php';
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function create_list(data){
            var table = $('#table');
            table.html('');
            var table_head = $('<tr>');
            table_head.append($('<th>').text('Box'))
            table_head.append($('<th>').text('Position'))
            table_head.append($('<th>').text('Player'))
            table_head.append($('<th>').text('Points'))
            table_head.append($('<th>').text('Place'))
            table.append(table_head);
            for(var x in data){
                var tr = $('<tr>');
                tr.append($('<td>').text(data[x].box_id));
                tr.append($('<td>').text(data[x].position));
                tr.append($('<td>').text(data[x].player));
                tr.append($('<td>').text(data[x].points));
                tr.append($('<td>').text(data[x].place));
                table.append(tr);
            };
        }
        $.ajax({
            url:'fetch.php?filter=1',
            type:'GET',
            success:function(data){
                var d = JSON.parse(data);
//              console.log(d);
                create_list(d);
            }
        });
        $('.filter').on('click',function(){
            var filter = $(this).val();
            var title = $(this).text();
            $('#selected').text(title);
            $.ajax({
            url:'fetch.php?filter='+filter,
            type:'GET',
            success:function(data){
                var d = JSON.parse(data);
//              console.log(d);
                create_list(d);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
        table {
            margin-top:10px;
        }
        table tr {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        table tr th {
            text-transform:uppercase;
            padding:5px 10px;
        }
        table tr td {
            padding:5px 10px;
        }
        table tr:nth-child(odd){
            background:#eee;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="clearfix"></div><br/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card-header">
           <h1> League Tables</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card-body">

            <button type="button" class="filter btn-primary" value=1>Singles</button>
            <button type="button" class="filter btn-primary" value=2>Ladies Doubles</button>
            <button type="button" class="filter btn-primary" value=3>Mens Doubles</button>
            <button type="button" class="filter btn-primary" value=4>Mixed Doubles</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" >
            <h3 id="selected">Singles</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" >
            <table class="table table-striped" id="table">
                <caption id="box"></caption>
            </table>
        </div> 
    </div>


<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

I wouldd like to populate the table caption with the box_id, and have a table for each box within the filtered league.

My problem is that I do not think I can loop through the array that I have produced to put each position, player, points & place in a box.  I think maybe I need to create a nested array. Perhaps before I encode it to json?

I have used (PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) to create a nested array and then use php foreach to populate html using php, so that I have data grouped by box_id. However this does not seem to work using json, or I cannot work our how to do it?
This is the ungrouped array:-

```
[{
    "box_id": "1",
    "league_id": "1",
    "position": "1",
    "player": "Caroline Hogan",
    "points": "27",
    "place": "0"
}, {
    "box_id": "1",
    "league_id": "1",
    "position": "2",
    "player": "Fran Gordon",
    "points": "11",
    "place": "0"
}, {
    "box_id": "1",
    "league_id": "1",
    "position": "3",
    "player": "Josh Handley",
    "points": "39",
    "place": "0"
}, {
    "box_id": "2",
    "league_id": "1",
    "position": "1",
    "player": "Gillian Shaw",
    "points": "0",
    "place": "0"
}, {
    "box_id": "2",
    "league_id": "1",
    "position": "2",
    "player": "Sally Westwood",
    "points": "0",
    "place": "0"
}, {
    "box_id": "2",
    "league_id": "1",
    "position": "3",
    "player": "Sandy Eley",
    "points": "0",
    "place": "0"
}]
```

This is the grouped array, where I cannot work out how to define box_id, etc.

```
{
    "1": [{
        "league_id": "1",
        "position": "1",
        "player": "Caroline Hogan",
        "points": "27",
        "place": "0"
    }, {
        "league_id": "1",
        "position": "2",
        "player": "Fran Gordon",
        "points": "11",
        "place": "0"
    }, {
        "league_id": "1",
        "position": "3",
        "player": "Josh Handley",
        "points": "39",
        "place": "0"
    }],
    "2": [{
        "league_id": "1",
        "position": "1",
        "player": "Gillian Shaw",
        "points": "0",
        "place": "0"
    }, {
        "league_id": "1",
        "position": "2",
        "player": "Sally Westwood",
        "points": "0",
        "place": "0"
    }, {
        "league_id": "1",
        "position": "3",
        "player": "Sandy Eley",
        "points": "0",
        "place": "0"
    }]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi. As far as I can understand, your problem is creating a json structure that match your need in php, right? Can you post (1) example your current json structure (the result of `echo json_encode($final)`) and (2) json structure you want/expect to create. I think it will help others to understand your problem better

Comment: Thank you. The following is the json with no grouping which works, but all boxes in one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for? It simply loops through the query result and put it into map by `box_id`:

```
$grouped = [];
foreach ($final as $m) {
  $box_id = $m['box_id'];
  if (empty($grouped[$box_id])) {
    $grouped[$box_id] = [];
  }
  unset($m['box_id']);
  array_push($grouped[$box_id], $m);
}
echo json_encode($grouped);
```

Result:

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "league_id": "1",
      "position": "1",
      "player": "Caroline Hogan",
      "points": "27",
      "place": "0"
    },
    {
      "league_id": "1",
      "position": "2",
      "player": "Fran Gordon",
      "points": "11",
      "place": "0"
    },
    {
      "league_id": "1",
      "position": "3",
      "player": "Josh Handley",
      "points": "39",
      "place": "0"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "league_id": "1",
      "position": "1",
      "player": "Gillian Shaw",
      "points": "0",
      "place": "0"
    },
    {
      "league_id": "1",
      "position": "2",
      "player": "Sally Westwood",
      "points": "0",
      "place": "0"
    },
    {
      "league_id": "1",
      "position": "3",
      "player": "Sandy Eley",
      "points": "0",
      "place": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

To display the result as tables with caption in js:

```js
const data = {"1":[{"league_id":"1","position":"1","player":"Caroline Hogan","points":"27","place":"0"},{"league_id":"1","position":"2","player":"Fran Gordon","points":"11","place":"0"},{"league_id":"1","position":"3","player":"Josh Handley","points":"39","place":"0"}],"2":[{"league_id":"1","position":"1","player":"Gillian Shaw","points":"0","place":"0"},{"league_id":"1","position":"2","player":"Sally Westwood","points":"0","place":"0"},{"league_id":"1","position":"3","player":"Sandy Eley","points":"0","place":"0"}]};

function create_list(data, container){
  Object.keys(data).forEach((boxId) => {
   container.append(create_table(boxId, data[boxId]));
  });
}

function create_table(boxId, data) {
    var table = $('<table>');
    table.append($('<caption>').text(boxId));
    var table_head = $('<tr>');
    table_head.append($('<th>').text('Position'))
    table_head.append($('<th>').text('Player'))
    table_head.append($('<th>').text('Points'))
    table_head.append($('<th>').text('Place'))
    table.append(table_head);
    for(let x in data){
        let tr = $('<tr>');
        tr.append($('<td>').text(data[x].position));
        tr.append($('<td>').text(data[x].player));
        tr.append($('<td>').text(data[x].points));
  tr.append($('<td>').text(data[x].place));
        table.append(tr);
    }
    return table;
}

create_list(data, $('#container'))
```

```css
table {
  margin: 2em 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  border-collapse: collapse;  
}

caption {
  margin: 2px 0;
}

caption, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I loop through this array in the create_list function so that each table has the box_id as the caption. I presume I have to loop twice so that table detail is within the caption. Unsure?

Comment: Thank you. It works fine if I paste the array that comes in from the ajax into your const data. However if I try to use the data directly in ajax i.e. success:function(array){
                create_list(array, $('#container'));
            }

Comment: You need to debug that. I can not do it for you. For example maybe it's because you need `JSON.parse(array)`  just like what you use in your previous code

Comment: Thank you. I thought I'd tried that, but obviously not. It populates perfectly now. My only problem now, is each time I click, a new table is created below the old. How do I clear the previous table(s)?

Comment: You can use jquery `remove()` or `empty()`. It's easy to google

Comment: Thank you I emptied the container on click. Thank you so much for your help. I'll look at objects & their keys now.